# Mount a shared volume between containers

Tags: docker, docker-volume

How to mount a volume that is used by many containers ?

Here is the command I use :

```
docker run -d  -it  --name shared  --mount shared:/app ubuntu:latest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong flag. Replace --mount with -v.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--mount` as below -

Create a container1 -

```
$ docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name container1 \
  --mount source=vol1,target=/app \
  nginx:latest
```

Create container2 -

```
$ docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name container2 \
  --mount source=vol1,target=/app \
  nginx:latest
```

Now whatever get written inside `/app` in any of the containers will get synced across all the containers using `source=vol1` .

Official Doc -

> Originally, the -v or --volume flag was used for standalone containers
>   and the --mount flag was used for swarm services. However, starting
>   with Docker 17.06, you can also use --mount with standalone
>   containers.

Hence you can use `--mount` for standalone containers as well since `Docker 17.06`